# how to add font files to custom theme in magento 2?

Tags: fonts, magento2

In Magento 2.0 , I have added google fonts`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" src_type="url" />` this line to default_blocks_head.xml but does't work? Anyone know about it?

Comment: Have you flushed the cache? Are you sure that theme is active. Can you test it? By removing header block for example?

Comment: did you find the reason for this? having the same issue

Comment: No, once you find the reason, please tell me.

Comment: if it doesn't solve please add your `default_blocks_head.xml` file